# Streaming video from server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a server which loads the video and a client which receives and displays the video. I'm new to python. the server code to load the video and send it to client/receiver.

```
server.py

import cv2
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 5005

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\testVideo.mp4')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)


    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    d = frame.flatten ()
    s = d.tostring ()

    for i in range(20):

        sock.sendto (s[i*46080:(i+1)*46080],(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The receiver code

```
import socket
import numpy
import cv2

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind ((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

s=""

while True:

    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(46080)

    s += data
    if len(s) == (46080*20):

        frame = numpy.fromstring (s,dtype=numpy.uint8)
        frame = frame.reshape (480,640,3)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        s=""

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord ('q'):
        break
```

I'm getting an error in "s += data"-**TypeError: must be str, not bytes**. Is there a problem with my append? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Just curious if my answer helped you solve this in any way! If it did, I'd be happy if you marked the answer as accepted. If not, maybe we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `s` is a string and `+` concatenates strings, but `data` is `byte()` (or perhaps even `bytearray`, not sure on that one yet). Edit: it seems to just hold a bytestring like `b\xff\xff\xff`

What you can do is reserve a `bytearray`-buffer, and then receive into that, since you seem to restrict filesize anyway (you check each iteration if your local (string)buffer is a certain length). With a maximum size, you just allocate that and read however much data comes through. If there's more, it's just cut off, and if it's less, the rest will be NULL-padded. Kind of like this:

```
# allocate 32 bytes as buffer
s = bytearray(32)
sock.recvmsg_into([s])
```

Test this by running the following Python code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("localhost", 8080))

# reserve a buffer of 4 bytes
s = bytearray(4)

sock.recvmsg_into([s])
```

At that point, the socket will block and wait for input. From a second terminal run this:

```
echo "foobar" | nc -u 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Your Python-script will continue execution and print what it received:

```
(4, [], 32, ('127.0.0.1', 56464))
>>> s
bytearray(b'foob')
```

If you *don't* want to go down that road, I have a solution to your original approach of just appending in an infinite loop. I previously posted a solution with appending to a `bytearray`, but that didn't work due to type mismatch. It turns out you don't even need `bytearray`, as this works as expected:

```
s = bytes()

while True:
    s += bytes(b'foobar')

    if s == b'foobarfoobar':
        print(s)
        break
```

Comment: sorry oliver, didnt work. got this error `s.append(data)
TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @SwaminathanS, I edited the answer. See if that helps, please